# What are the moisture related issues in the use of Stucco and EIFS in the building construction Industry?

Tags: civil-engineering

I am investigating the use of stucco masonry versus Exterior Insulation and Finish Systems (EIFS) in the construction industry. I have no knowledge or training in this matter and my knowledge is limited to what I have read in the past few days.

#### Stucco

[image: Stucco Cross Section]

As I understand it, both stucco and EIFS have a long history in the building construction industry. I have also read that there are two type of EIFS, PB (polymer-based) and PM (polymer modified) systems widely used in the building construction industry.

#### Exterior Insulation and Finish Systems (EIFS)

[image: Exterior Insulation and Finish System]

**Question:** What are the moisture related issues in the of Stucco and EIFS with regards to mold buildup with respect to **corrugated aluminum siding**? Once again my primary interest is with to respect to moisture and mold.

---

**References:**

- [How do I mitigate moisture problems when putting up drywall over stucco with torn tar paper?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/how-do-i-mitigate-moisture-problems-when-putting-up-drywall-over-stucco-with-tor)
- [Exterior insulation finishing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_insulation_finishing_system)
- [EIFS vs. Stucco: What’s the Difference?](http://www.pieglobal.com/eifs-vs-stucco-whats-the-difference/)
- [Stucco System](http://www.firstext.com/stucco.php)

Comment: Even though you're focusing on moisture and mold concerns, this still seems a bit broad.  I think your question would be a bit stronger if you laid out some of the things you think you've found.  Getting confirmation regarding research findings seems to be more easily answered than a broader "pros and cons of X vs. Y with respect to Z."

Comment: Too broad. Also, it's absurd to say "both stucco and EIFS have a long history in the building construction industry" - one's been around for a handful of decades, the other for millennia. And the references you provide already answer all of the questions you've asked. So what exactly is the specific engineering concept you're having difficulty with?